# Tem como dar um continue no foreach sem sair do while?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$array = array(
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 166.93 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46091"  , "Total" => 41.2 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 25.39 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 25.39 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46098",   "Total" => -1179.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46098",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46094",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
   [ "IdMovimento" => "46094",   "Total" => 1009.9 ]
);

$totalVendas = 0;

foreach ($array as $vendas) {

   $id = $vendas['IdMovimento'];

   $venda = 0;

   while ($id == $vendas['IdMovimento']) {
      
      $venda += $vendas['Total'];
      $totalVendas = $totalVendas + $vendas]['Total'];

      continue 2;

   }

   echo $venda."<br>";

}

echo $totalVendas;
```

Na linha `continue 2;` o php retorna ao começo do foreach, setando novamente o `$id`, queria saber se há uma possibilidade de avançar a array `$vendas` do foreach sem sair do loop `while ($id == $vendas['IdMovimento'])`.

O objetivo do código é somar o total em que o IdMovimento é o mesmo, mostrando o resultado desse idmovimento após a soma dele, e após todas os outros IdMovimento serem mostrados, mostrar um total geral.

Comment: Posso ter entendido errado, mas no lugar desse `continue 2` o `break` já resolveria, ainda sim o while não faz muito sentido, porque não esta iterando nada de fato, esta apenas comparando 2 valores que você já possui, nem precisaria do while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código possui erro de lógica, esse seu `while` seria um loop infinito, daí o `continue` irá encerrar o loop. Nesse seu caso, usar um `if` te atenderia melhor. E mesmo assim, o `if` sempre será verdadeiro pois a validação que está sendo feita é basicamente `$id == $id`. O que você precisa, é agrupar os ids, e somá-los, daí, você terá a soma de todos.

```
$array = array(
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 166.93 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46091"  , "Total" => 41.2 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 25.39 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46091", "Total" => 25.39 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46098",   "Total" => -1179.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46098",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46095",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46094",   "Total" => 1009.9 ],
  [ "IdMovimento" => "46094",   "Total" => 1009.9 ]
);

$totalVendas = []; // array que agrupará as suas vendas

foreach($array as $venda) {

  $id    = $venda['IdMovimento'];
  $total = $venda['Total'];

  if(array_key_exists($id, $totalVendas)) // verifica se o seu array já possui um id, para eles não se repetirem
     $totalVendas[$id]+=$total;
  else
     $totalVendas[$id] = $total; // adiciona o novo id para o somar na próxima iteração

}
```

Assim, o seu `$totalVendas` será um array agrupado por id, tendo o total das suas vendas.

Comment: Seguindo essa lógica funcionou. Mas a minha dúvida mesmo era se eu consigo avançar o recordset do foreach sem voltar ao início do foreach, ou seja, dentro do while eu avançaria a linha do foreach (não entrando em loop), e assim que o Id trocasse, ele pararia de somar (saindo do while) e me daria o resultado daquele Id, seguindo assim para os próximos

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer pular a iteração do foreach dentro do seu while? Dentro do while não seria possível, pq o comando `continue` seria referente ao seu while. Você pode deixar uma `$flag` dentro do seu while, e atribuir um valor a ela, daí quando sair do seu while, fazer uma condicional em cima dessa `$flag` e daí "pular" a iteração do foreach